# Azure RunBook - Can We pass the key to a file zip the file and push it to a blob (Key refresh)

Tags: powershell, azure-runbook

i am able to create a run book to generate a key and passed into a variable using powershell.
can i move the key into a txt file and zip the same and move it to blob.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use below script to accomplish the requirement of sending a value into a text file, then to zip it and then sending it to a storage blob.

```
$storageAccountName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$storageAccountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$KeyValue = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$KeyValue | Out-File -FilePath ($env:temp+"/KeyFile.txt")
Compress-Archive -Path ($env:temp+"/KeyFile.txt") -DestinationPath ($env:temp+"/KeyFileZip.zip") -CompressionLevel optimal
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File ($env:temp+"/KeyFileZip.zip") -Container "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -BlobType "Block" -Context $context -Verbose
```

Make sure you update the storage account name, storage account key and container name correctly before using the script.

For illustration on how I accomplished it, please check below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thankks a lot!!! sir just worked like butter....and step whise explanation

Comment: hi krishan is it possible for us to mail to a conserned person with out usng logic apps directly from run book

Comment: hi malcolm richard, Yes, you can send email from a runbook. For more details w.r.t it, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-send-email) document. BTW glad that I am able to help you. Feel free to accept the above answer.Thanks.